# Armature Posing Abnormal Hip Line & Legs Cave In

Tags: armature, weight-painting, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I made an armature and connected it so a stick figure I made. The issue I'm running into is when I bend the knees of the armature. The upper thighs of the figure begin to cave in, and a line appears in the hip area. This is an issue I've had for a while that I normally fix with sculpting, but I'd like a more permanent solution.

I've tried editing the weight paint of the hip area and the legs, but can't seem to find a fix. Any advice or links to a video on this topic would be appreciated. Thanks

[image: Before moving hip joint]

[image: After moving hip joint]

[image: Removed armature to show texture]

Comment: Hello please share your file (remove the top of your character as it is not useful): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=qBO2eA41" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/qBO2eA41/)

Done, I had a minor revelation that I think may solve the issue. I tried adding loops _before_ parenting the armature to the figure and then did automatic weights and it seemed to help. Is this the way to go, or is there another route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the *Subdivision Surface* modifier under the *Armature* modifier so that it's the low-poly mesh that is animated, not the (virtually) subdivided mesh (also maybe activate the *Preserve Volume* option of the *Armature* modifier):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! And Preserve Volume did make a decent difference, it kept some of the width of the arms and legs when they were moved. Will keep this in mind for the future